# Env vars with Azure DevOps releases together with Azure App Service and Docker

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

We have a pipeline that builds a NodeJS project that needs some environment variables to point to different API's depending on where it's hosted. We want to use the build once concept, moving from dev to staging and finally production.

We've used the "Configuration" menu to add environment variables, and it works great. However, our operations would like to get it into the Release pipeline, but I can't get it to pass varaibles to the App Service.

I've been using the "Variables" tab in Releases and they seem only accessable from within the pipeline, they're not passed *to* the environment.

Is it even possible doing this? For me it feels logical to have the env varaibles in the App Service but I want to make operations life as easy as possible.

Comment: How do you deploy to the App Service?

Comment: We do that through Azure Dev Ops, we just follow a standard guided form to set it up.

Comment: Can you share your "Deploy to Azure App Service" task?

Comment: The env variable defined in your pipeline is for the agents where your pipeline runs. If you want to set environment variable for the hosted environment of your application, there are some ways to set env variable according to your environment, or you can try setging these variable in your app's config file and have your code read from the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Using "Deploy Azure App Service" setting.

Under Pipelines > Releases > Edit > (Select stage) > "Deploy Azure App Service" > Application and Configuration Settings > App Settings

There you can add env. variables in this format.

`-ENV_VAR_KEY myvalue`

Answer (score 1):

I see you have your answer but thought I'd also chip in with an alternative. We have a similar requirement but also need to update connection strings on other webapps that are different to the deployment target webapp.

For this I run an Azure CLI command in a `foreach` loop against webapp and connection string arrays

```
az webapp config connection-string set --resource-group $ResourceGroup --name $WebApp --connection-string-type SQLAzure --settings $String
```